# How to limit Azure Functions Calls per user/ip/mac/etc?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm using azure functions which work great for me.
But my concern is:
How can I avoid hackers from doing "mass api calls" in order to hack me or to raise my billing for example?

Comment: You simply can't. I'm sure they'll block single IPs if they send too many requests but you can't really do much against a bot-network. But.. do you already have a few million users? Because: It's not a problem until you do and once you do it won't be a problem. At least not yours.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/274916/azure-functions-are-accessed-publicly-by-default-i-2.html

Comment: @StefanFalk thank you. I don't have million users but i'm concerned of some freak trigger millions of requests which can make my billing skyrocket!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use API Management in front of your Azure Functions and their rate limit / throttling policies:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-flexible-throttling

Comment: that is exactly what i was looking for. thank you

Comment: FYI: doesn't work on APIM Consumption plan.